# Materialize - dropdown doesn't work

Tags: materialize

I am using materialize framework for ui design. If you look at my [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/NOxHehqbtvK0lTZ5uGVs) , the dropdown doesn't show. Please help.

```
<div class="input-field col s3">
    <select>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        <option value="1">USD</option>
        <option value="2">CAD</option>
        <option value="3">HDK</option>
    </select>
    <label>Select Currency</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You must initialize the `select` in your JavaScript. Put the following code just before closing your `body`tag and it should work fine.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('select').material_select();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I would love to discuss this more with you. Can you please reach out to me via my e mail on my profile or let me know how i can connect with you.

Comment: What if I have only a list of `<li>` items and not a `<select>`, do I still need to initialize it with `$(document).ready` ?

Answer (score 1):

First you must include file jquery in your html before your file materialize.js, then you must initialize the select element. In addition, you will need a separate call for any dynamically generated select elements your page generates.
Modify your code, see: [Select Materialize](http://plnkr.co/edit/eCOOrIMNhM8J7OUtUlx5)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $('select').material_select();
     });    
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I would love to discuss this more with you. Can you please reach out to me via my e mail on my profile or let me know how i can connect with you.

Comment: Could you provide an additional example of how to properly structure a call for dynamically generated select elements? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have added complete code for materialize select in one `html` file. I have added `JavaScript` code bottom of the `body` which should be your problem for not working the code. When you create separate flies, you should add `JavaScript` and `css` files' paths to your `html` code relevant order.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Select</title>
 <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css">
 <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>

<body class="row">

 <!-- your code start --> 
 <div class="input-field col s11 m11 l11">  
     <select>
         <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
         <option value="1">USD</option>
         <option value="2">CAD</option>
         <option value="3">HDK</option>
     </select>
     <label>Select Currency</label>        
 </div>
    <!-- your code end -->
     
 <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('select').material_select();
  });
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

When you add external libraries or files to your `html` file the order is important.

Answer (score 0):

You must be sure that you initialize the select with jquery or JS.
Copy paste this line in your code in the document ready:

```
$('select').material_select();
```