# Initializing Materialize functions

Tags: javascript, materialize

I am having trouble initializing some Materialize-css javascript functions; the one in particular is material_select().

I am trying to initialize the function as stated in the Materialize docs:

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
  });`

However, I get the following error:
`$(...).material_select is not a function`

`material_select()` as well as any other Materialize function initializes if I manually write it into the browser console, but not if it's in the code; I am importing jQuery before materialize.js as well.

Help is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You are most likely loading materialize.js before jQuery or your jQuery version is too high and not working with materialize. You need to add some code here!

Comment: Importing jQuery before Materialize solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

Double check that jQuery and Materialize are initialized before the document ready function is called.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
});
</script>
```

And of course make sure that the appropriate CSS files are imported in `<head>`

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to give the exact solution without referring your code. Problem may be happened in the `materialize.js` file. It would be better if you test following fully working code and find your issue.

[Working code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33841623/3213745)

Click `Run Code Snippet` in the given link for live demo or copy full code and test in your machine.